# Mysql / swap space full

Tags: swap, mysql

I have MySQL Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45 server running on Multiflex Intel Blade having 8G of RAM &  8 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5410 @ 2.33GHz.

The problems I am facing are:

1. For the last 3-4 days my 2G swap space is getting full & the server goes into hangged state and I need to reboot the server each time.

   Output of `free -m`:

   ```
                total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
   Mem:          7971        933       7037          0          0        800
   -/+ buffers/cache:        132       7838
   Swap:         1983        785       1198
   ```
2. I have added 2G more swap space but still problem exists.

   `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p -e "show variables like '%cache%';"`:

   ```
   +------------------------------+----------------------+
   | Variable_name                | Value                |
   | binlog_cache_size            | 32768                | 
   | have_query_cache             | YES                  | 
   | key_cache_age_threshold      | 300                  | 
   | key_cache_block_size         | 1024                 | 
   | key_cache_division_limit     | 100                  | 
   | max_binlog_cache_size        | 18446744073709551615 | 
   | ndb_cache_check_time         | 0                    | 
   | query_cache_limit            | 1048576              | 
   | query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096                 | 
   | query_cache_size             | 536870912            | 
   | query_cache_type             | ON                   | 
   | query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF                  | 
   | table_cache                  | 1024                 | 
   | thread_cache_size            | 16                   |
   ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Smells like a memory link. What's using up virtual memory? Look at the output from `top` or `htop` (sorted by memory), and see what process is growing over time.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a great article](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space) on how the Linux kernel handles swap space. "swappiness," or the likelihood that the kernel will swap out large programs into swap space can be decreased so that the swap space is not preferred over RAM.

Echoing a value from 0-100 to /proc/sys/vm/swappiness will cause the kernel to swap less or more depending on the value. The default is 60. I'd recommend something like 40-50.

You may want to actually *reduce* the amount of swap space, as that bottleneck may be the "hanged" state you describe.

Comment: Except that high swappiness will never cause a server to hang, because eventually RAM will be filled as well, and the buffers will be dropped.